React native Routing/Navigation between screens not working
I am unable to get my react native naviagtion screen working. I am trying to access two screens, one CancerHomepageWeb and the other ChemoHomepageWeb. I would like to put the screen name is the routing URL to access each screen. Here is my code:
index.js
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { CancerHomepageWeb } from './CancerHomepageWeb.js';
import { ChemoHomepageWeb } from './ChemoHomepageWeb.js';
import { MainSideBarWeb } from './MainSideBarWeb.js';
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
    return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="CancerHomepageWeb">
            <Stack.Screen
                name="CancerHomepageWeb"
                component={CancerHomepageWeb}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
                name="ChemoHomepageWeb"
                component={ChemoHomepageWeb}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
export default registerRootComponent(App);

CancerHomepageWeb.js
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useState, Component, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Modal,
  Pressable
} from "react-native";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import constants from './Constants.js';
import { styles } from './CommonStylesWeb.js';
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';
import { MainSideBarWeb } from './MainSideBarWeb'

const CancerHomepageWeb = ({navigation}) => {
    const [cancerWiki, setCancerWiki] = useState("");
    const [cancerType, setCancerType] = useState("");
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);
    const [selectedLabel, setSelectedLabel] = useState(null);
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
    const [cancerWikiContent, setCancerWikiContent] = useState("");
    //const navigation = useNavigation();
    console.log("navigation ", navigation);
    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {

            var urlCancerWiki = await constants.getServerURL() + 'cancers_wiki';
            console.warn(urlCancerWiki);
            let resultCancerWiki = await fetch(urlCancerWiki, {
                method: "GET", mode: 'cors'
                }).then(response => response.json())
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response) {
                            console.warn(response)
                            setCancerWiki(response)
                        }
                });
        };
        getData();
    }, []);
    async function handleChangeCancer(value, index) {
      console.warn("CANCER HAS CHANGED");
      setSelectedValue(value);
      console.warn(value)
      if(index > 0) {
          indexOffset = index - 1;
          console.warn(options[indexOffset].label);
          setSelectedLabel(options[indexOffset].label);

          const url = await constants.getServerURL() + 'cancer_wiki';
          console.warn(url);
          let result = fetch(url, {
             method: 'POST',
             headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
             body: JSON.stringify({ id: value}),
             mode: 'cors'
           }).then(response => response.json())
             .then(response => {
                if (response) {
                    setCancerWikiContent(response)
                    setCancerWiki("")
                }
           });

      }
    };
    const searchCancers = async() => {
        const url = await constants.getServerURL() + 'cancer_name';
        console.warn(url);
        console.warn(cancerType);
        if (cancerType.length >= 3) {
            let result = fetch(url, {
               method: 'POST',
               headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
               body: JSON.stringify({ cancer_type: cancerType}),
               mode: 'cors'
             }).then(response => response.json())
               .then(response => {
               setOptions([]);
               optionsTemp = [];
               console.warn("GETTING CANCER RESPONSE")
               console.warn(response)
               if (response) {
                    //setCancer = response.cancers
                    console.warn("VALID CANCER RESPONSE")
                    response.map( (cancer) => {
                        optionsTemp.push(new Object({label:cancer.name , value: cancer.id}));
                    });
                    console.warn(optionsTemp)
                    setOptions(optionsTemp);
               } else {
                   console.warn("Error retrieving Cancer");
                   //setErrorMessage("Error Getting Cancers!");
                   //setErrorVisible(true);
               }
              });
        }
    }
    return (

    <View style={styles.sideBar}>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.TextInput}
              placeholder="Cancers"
              placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
              onChangeText={(cancerType) => setCancerType(cancerType)}
              onKeyPress={searchCancers}
            />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Select Cancer</Text>
            <RNPickerSelect
              items={options}
              onValueChange={(value, index)  =>
                handleChangeCancer(value,index)}
              value={selectedValue}
            />
            {selectedValue && <Text>Selected: {selectedLabel}</Text>}
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
             <View style={styles.inputView}>
                 <Text>{cancerWikiContent}</Text>
                 <Text>{cancerWiki}</Text>
             </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
);
}



export { CancerHomepageWeb };

ChemoHomepageWeb.js
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useState, Component, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Modal,
  Pressable
} from "react-native";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import constants from './Constants.js';
import { styles } from './CommonStylesWeb.js';
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';
import { MainSideBarWeb } from './MainSideBarWeb'

const ChemoHomepageWeb = ({navigation}) => {
    const [chemoWiki, setChemoWiki] = useState("");
    const [chemoType, setChemoType] = useState("");
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);
    const [selectedLabel, setSelectedLabel] = useState(null);
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
    const [chemoWikiContent, setChemoWikiContent] = useState("");
    //const navigation = useNavigation();
    console.log("navigation ", navigation);
    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {

            var urlChemoWiki = await constants.getServerURL() + 'chemos_wiki';
            console.warn(urlChemoWiki);
            let resultChemoWiki = await fetch(urlChemoWiki, {
                method: "GET", mode: 'cors'
                }).then(response => response.json())
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response) {
                            console.warn(response)
                            setChemoWiki(response)
                        }
                });
        };
        getData();
    }, []);
    async function handleChangeChemo(value, index) {
      console.warn("CHEMO HAS CHANGED");
      setSelectedValue(value);
      console.warn(value)
      if(index > 0) {
          indexOffset = index - 1;
          console.warn(options[indexOffset].label);
          setSelectedLabel(options[indexOffset].label);

          const url = await constants.getServerURL() + 'chemo_wiki';
          console.warn(url);
          let result = fetch(url, {
             method: 'POST',
             headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
             body: JSON.stringify({ id: value}),
             mode: 'cors'
           }).then(response => response.json())
             .then(response => {
                if (response) {
                    setChemoWikiContent(response)
                    setChemoWiki("")
                }
           });

      }
    };
    const searchChemos = async() => {
        const url = await constants.getServerURL() + 'chemo_name';
        console.warn(url);
        console.warn(chemoType);
        if (chemoType.length >= 3) {
            let result = fetch(url, {
               method: 'POST',
               headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
               body: JSON.stringify({ chemo_type: chemoType}),
               mode: 'cors'
             }).then(response => response.json())
               .then(response => {
               setOptions([]);
               optionsTemp = [];
               console.warn("GETTING CHEMO RESPONSE")
               console.warn(response)
               if (response) {
                    console.warn("VALID CHEMO RESPONSE")
                    response.map( (chemo) => {
                        optionsTemp.push(new Object({label:chemo.name , value: chemo.id}));
                    });
                    console.warn(optionsTemp)
                    setOptions(optionsTemp);
               } else {
                   console.warn("Error retrieving Chemo drug");
                   //setErrorMessage("Error Getting Chemo drugss!");
                   //setErrorVisible(true);
               }
              });
        }
    }
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.TextInput}
              placeholder="CHemo"
              placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
              onChangeText={(chemoType) => setChemoType(chemoType)}
              onKeyPress={searchChemos}
            />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
            <Text>Select Chemo Drug</Text>
            <RNPickerSelect
              items={options}
              onValueChange={(value, index)  =>
                handleChangeChemo(value,index)}
              value={selectedValue}
            />
            {selectedValue && <Text>Selected: {selectedLabel}</Text>}
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
             <View style={styles.inputView}>
                 <Text>{chemoWikiContent}</Text>
                 <Text>{chemoWiki}</Text>
             </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
);
}



export { ChemoHomepageWeb };

Here is my package.json
{
  "name": "cancerhacked",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "~51.0.28",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.23",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-network-info": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^9.3.1",
    "react-native-public-ip": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}


Whatever route I put in my localhost I always get the Cancer App. If I put a navigation call to the Chemo screen navigation.navigate("ChemoHomepageWeb") it still goes to the Cancer page not the Chemo. Any help is welcome.
